# Franz's desktop notifications is not working

Tags: unity, notification, franz

Is there a way to enable desktop notifications (sort of Windows 10) in Ubuntu. They are so convenient to use with email clients and messengers.

I use [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/) and have enabled desktop notifications for all my accounts but they don't show up in notification bar.

Comment: Unity has notification at the top bar. And specific application has desktop notifications such as Telegram

Comment: I use Franz and enabled desktop notifications but they dont show up at the top bar.

Comment: If your question is specific about an application, edit the question to include them.

Comment: It's still in beta version and as such, beta versions may not always work as expected